# No ansible roles were found in Satellite 6.4 - system roles installed

Tags: ansible, redhat, satellite

I have an RHN Satellite 6.4 Server and have installed rhel-system-roles as per documentation.

```
yum install rhel-system-roles
```

But when I click inside the GUI on **Configure->Ansible->Roles** I get the error:

> no ansible roles were found in satellite.

I have also copied some roles from the **system-roles** folder to ***/etc/ansible/roles/*** and also made a **test_role** folder there but still cannot import or see them inside the GUI.

I have restarted the server. Can this be why I do not have a host that is connected ok without errors inside hosts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please elaborate your query **"Can this be why I do not have a host that is connected ok without errors inside hosts"**

Comment: Hi. This was only a suggestion. I have some test nodes that are maybe not reachable but I am not sure if this could be connected with the issue that I do not see the ansible roles.

Comment: Hi. Is there maybe anyone that has the similar issues.